# How to make coova chilli works without radius?

Tags: ubuntu, hotspot

I have coova chilli installed on my gateway.
I want to configure coova chili to redirect the authentication to an external captive portal. The authentication will be done by the external captive portal which contains its own data base of credentials (It does not use Radius).

I do not want the coova chilli use radius authentication. I want the coova chilli use the captive data base credential authentication.

Is it possible to do that with coova chilli?

Comment: AFAIK, you need to use `chilli_query authenticate`. Otherwise coovachilli redirects to external UAM with a `challenge`. The UAM authenticates the user and redirects to coovachilli with the radius username and password encoded with the pre-shared secret & challenge. Coovachilli then decodes the credentials and verifies using RADIUS. If the radius returns `Access-Accept`, coovachilli accepts the user. If you don't have radius, you need to design your own authentication page and call `chilli_query authenticate` after successful verification

Comment: BDW, You can also use local users. [see this](https://coova.github.io/mail-archive/chilli/2013-February/002186.html). You need to try the above resources and build your own solution. You can always ask the solution to a specific problem but please never expect others to build the whole for you. :) Coovachilli expects username and password encoded with the preshared secret. So, you need to design the external captive portal page to handle this. I have a sample PHP script which does this.

Comment: @Mohamed, have you found your answer? I'm kind of the same boat. I only want chilli and not any radius.

Answer (score 0):

One question gives your answer.
How will coova-chilli know that authentication is succeed or failed ?
So radius does that job for coova-chilli.

You need to make coova-chilli aware that client is authenticated and it should get internet access.

So, if you don't want to use radius there is one way.
On success, you should execute chilli_query with valid params to authenticate that client coova-chilli side.